# Comparing data from two different columns in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm trying to figure out how to compare the percent difference between two columns using st.selectbox
This is the code I have:

```
df=pd.read_csv('df.csv')

select1 = st.selectbox('Option 1', options=df.columns)
select2 = st.selectbox('Option 2', options=df.columns)
x_axis_val = df["Name"]
y_axis_val = (select1/select2)*100
plot = px.bar(df, x=x_axis_val, y=y_axis_val, template="plotly_dark")
st.plotly_chart(plot, use_container_width=True)
```

The error I get is this

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

I've tried

```
int(select1)/int(select2)
```

And then I get the error

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Score'

All the columns in df contain numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code.

```
# df=pd.read_csv('df.csv')
data = [['Lakers', 95, 20], ['Clippers', 125, 35], ['Celtics', 130, 25]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Score', 'Rebound'])

st.dataframe(df)

sb_options = list(df.columns)
sb_options.pop(0)  # remove the Name col for selectbox option

select1 = st.selectbox('Option 1', options=sb_options)
select2 = st.selectbox('Option 2', options=sb_options)

x_axis_val = df["Name"]

y_axis_val = (df[select1]/df[select2])*100

title = f'Ratio of {select1} and {select2}'
plot = px.bar(df, x=x_axis_val, y=y_axis_val, template="plotly_dark", title=title)

# Update the y-axis label.
plot.update_layout(
    yaxis_title=f'{select1} / {select2} Pct'
)
st.plotly_chart(plot, use_container_width=True)
```

##### Output

[image]